# How to optimise this layout XML file to match my idea?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've created this fragment named searchfragment. Below there is the layout XML file of the searchfragment. Unfortunatelly the design isn't that smooth as I want it to be.

Here's what I wanted it to look like:
First row: Welcoming text (that works)
Second row: Search input field (that works, too)
Thirt row (and here it gets complicated): There should be a text named "Search for" and then a Spinner with the item you can search for (e.g. name, year, price). Then there's the Search button. Next thing is that you can sort the output. Therefore there's a text with "Sort for", a Spinner with the critirion and a Sort button. Best case the search section should be align to the left and the sort for to the right, but still centered.
Forth row: Output field.
Now as the elements are all present on my device, they are not in the graphical layout of Eclipse. I've tried for hours now to get it working but it's kind of hard if you're not sseing your objects.

Long text - short task: Please help me optimise my design.

searchfragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_for" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/criterion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:entries="@array/searcharray"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sort_for"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sort"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:entries="@array/sortarray"
                android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sort_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="sortAgain"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I've added a photo of the current design. The space with the red frame around it is the third "row" and should be changed. The second spinner is (I don't know why) much too wide. It should be that wide as the first one. Then all the elements should be about the same heigth and the elements should be centered.

[image: Current state]

Comment: It will be helpful to post an image of the layout you would like to achieve.

Comment: done. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your layout, but the reason your second `Spinner` is taking up so much room is that you've set it's `layout_weight` to 1, and as it's the only one with a `layout_weight`, it's taking up the rest of the space that's free.

If you want the items to take up a relative amount of space on the screen, then you could stick with using `layout_weight` and give all of your items that property.

For example, just for your third row you would get rid of the `LinearLayout` around your `Spinner`, change some of the `layout_width` properties and give all of your items a `layout_weight`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/search_for" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/criterion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:entries="@array/searcharray"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/android"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sort_for"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/sortarray"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sort_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/android"
        android:onClick="sortAgain"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is going to give all of your items an equal weighting, so the `TextViews` will be the same size as the `Spinners` which will be the same size as the `Buttons`. Play around with the `layout_weight` attribute to make them more relative, for example if you want the `Buttons` to be twice the size as the `Spinners`, set their `layout_weight` to 2.